# fancybox2 - how to autosize the fancybox after it was loaded

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm loading content into a fancybox2 and I need it to autosize dynamically after the content was loaded.
How do I achieve this?
Thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing `$.fancybox.update();` after changing contents (make sure you are using the latest version).